# Calculate the volume of the region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Calculate the volume of the region inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and outside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=b^2$, where $a > b,$ by using an appropriate double integral.

I was using polar coordinates, but had a problem of writing it out. Can somebody help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how.

> $$ 2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b} (\sqrt{a^2-r^2}) rdrd\theta. $$

**Note:** We used the formula

> $$ \iint_{D} (f_1(x,y)-f_2(x,y))dydx. $$

In your case you have the following

> $$ f_1(x,y) = \sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)},\quad f_2(x,y) = -\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}. $$

Comment: @MachtKuhn: Have you finished the problem?

Comment: Yeah. It's just what you wrote right? It is basically calculating the intersection between two curves. In this case, the top curve is the sphere and the bottom curve is the cylinder. Right? And here you used polar coordinate. Nice!

Comment: @MachtKuhn: Yes. Good job.

Comment: Thanks!alkdjfbqo#@(!*&10328910

Comment: Oh can you explain further what does f2(x,y) stand for in detail? I am a little bit confused. Thanks!

Comment: Because the volume of the shape you want to find is bounded top and bottom by the sphere. Plot the sphere and cylinder and look at the wanted shape.

Comment: Ahh I get it! Thanks!

Comment: @MachtKuhn: I recommend you always draw the shape to see what's going on.

Comment: @MachtKuhn: For accepting the answer I think there is a box where you can click on it.

Comment: Um... where is the box?

Comment: @MachtKuhn: I think it is a green box, right.

Comment: Is that a tick?